# Is there a way to run Checkstyle only on .java files WITHOUT ANT?

Tags: java, ant, checkstyle

I'm trying have Checkstyle be given any file type, but ignore anything that is not a .java file.
I created a filter, but that doesn't seem to be working:

```
public class DotJavaFilter
    extends AutomaticBean
    implements Filter
{

    public DotJavaFilter()
        throws PatternSyntaxException
    {
    }

    public boolean accept(AuditEvent aEvent)
    {
        final String fileName = aEvent.getFileName();
        return fileName.endsWith(".java");
    }
}
```

I'd like to give CS a directory of files and have it only process the .java ones.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 7):

You can run it on the command line like this:

```
java -jar checkstyle-5.5-all.jar -c docs/sun_checks.xml -r /path/to/src
```

If you are using bash, you can turn on `globstar` and then process only java files like this:

```
shopt -s globstar
java -jar checkstyle-5.5-all.jar -c docs/sun_checks.xml -r /path/to/src/**/*.java
```

Checkstyle command line documentation is [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html).

---

**Update: Using a suppression filter**

Create a suppressions file which to ignore all checks on class files. You can add regexes for other file types you are not interested as well.

**suppressions.xml:**

```
<suppressions>
    <suppress checks="." files=".*\.class"/>
</suppressions>
```

Add a suppression filter to your checks file:

**my_checks.xml:**

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

Run it:

```
java -jar checkstyle-5.5-all.jar -c my_checks.xml -r /path/to/src
```

Documentation on Suppression Filters can be found [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't quite work like that.  If you give CS a module directory which has has source files and compiled class files in it...CS will find&scan the .java files along with the .class files.  My users don't want it to pickup non-java files.

Comment: CORRECTION: that does work using sun_checks.xml.  When I put in my own config file, it picks up everything.

Comment: thank you dogbane, this is what i am looking for.  However, I can't get it to work.  My supressions.xml looks just like yours and i still see .class files being listed as being processed.  CS doesn't flag any of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine with `shopt -s globstar`. This is the syntax I use:
`java -jar checkstyle-5.6-all.jar -r src/**/*.java -c sun_checks.xml -f xml -o checkstyle-result.xml`

Comment: Unknown option: '-r'. It looks like the -r parameter no longer exists.  ( using checkstyle-8.41.1-all.jar ) https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/cmdline.html.  The documentation shows "MyClass.java" SINGLE examples.  :(