# how to make checkstyle ignore xml files in my application

Tags: static-analysis, checkstyle

i've configured my checkstyle plugin with customized checkstyle.xml and it works fine with the java classes but having a lot of warnings with the xml files can anyone suggest how to disable the check style from any xml file in my application.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to do that:

- You could [suppress findings from non-Java files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386364/is-there-a-way-to-run-checkstyle-only-on-java-files-without-ant). This works very well inside and outside of your IDE.
- If you are using Eclipse, you can also configure Eclipse not to feed the non-Java files to Checkstyle. In order to do that, right-click your project and click *Checkstyle*. Uncheck *use simple configuration*. Specify a file set using `\.java$` as regexp. You will see the list of files in the bottom half of the dialog window change to only Java files.

In earlier versions of Checkstyle, I think I remember that there also was a file name filter in the configuration XML, but I can't seem to find it in the docs now, so maybe that feature is no more.

Answer (score 1):

There is a basedir property at the start of the Checker module in the check style config file. Uncomment it if it is commented. 
Set it's value to the folder you want to apply your checkstyle rules to. 
E.g. src folder of any eclipse project only contains java files.

```
<!-- If you set the basedir property below, then all reported file names 
    will be relative to the specified directory. See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/5.x/config.html#Checker --> 
    <property name="basedir" value="/MyEclipeProject/src"/>
```